# How to run a SQL query with a changing database name as a parameter on a list of databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query which consist of the database_name parameter in several places of this query/than I have a list of databases in a .txt file. How to run this query step by step one after another on each database from the .txt file (the database_name in the query file has to be changed with every interaction). Thank you in advance!

Comment: I was trying to use sqlcmd but I am not sure how the command should look like to use database_name (from the .txt file) as a parameter in my sql query.

Comment: I did something like that:
sqlcmd -S <SQLSERVERNAME> -i script.sql -d datbases.txt
but I am not sure how the script should "take" as the parameter the datbase name from the .txt file

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Something about this setup just sounds wrong, wrong, wrong.

Comment: We have done similar things using powershell to in turn call sqlcmd. We read the DB name from a text file using powershell and set a sqlcmd variable to the db name and invoke a command or script that references the variable using sqlcmd.

Answer (score 0):

- Read the .txt file into a temporary table
- Loop through table
  -- Create a variable and populate with SQL and database name
  -- Use sp_executesql to execute
- Loop